# Find First Specific Byte in a Byte[] Array c#

Tags: c#, design-patterns, arrays, search

I have a byte array and wish to find the first occurance (if any) of a specific byte.

Can you guys help me with a nice, elegant and efficient way to do it?

```
 /// Summary
/// Finds the first occurance of a specific byte in a byte array.
/// If not found, returns -1.
public int GetFirstOccurance(byte byteToFind, byte[] byteArray)
{

}
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
public static int GetFirstOccurance(byte byteToFind, byte[] byteArray)
{
   return Array.IndexOf(byteArray,byteToFind);
}
```

It will return -1 if not found

Or as Sam pointed out, an extension method:

```
public static int GetFirstOccurance(this byte[] byteArray, byte byteToFind)
{
   return Array.IndexOf(byteArray,byteToFind);
}
```

Or to make it generic:

```
public static int GetFirstOccurance<T>(this T[] array, T element)
{
   return Array.IndexOf(array,element);
}
```

Then you can just say:

```
int firstIndex = byteArray.GetFirstOccurance(byteValue);
```

Comment: You could make this a static method!

Comment: extension method too, but only in C# 3.0

Comment: What's the point of creating a wrapper for a standard library function? This just makes code harder to read because you have to look up the definition of the custom function. In particular a pointless wrapper like this smells of something unexpected hidden inside.

Answer (score 15):

[Array.IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.indexof.aspx)?

Answer (score 3):

Since you mentioned efficiency, here is some **heavily optimized C# code** I've written which uses native addressing and maximal qword-aligned reading to cut the number of memory accesses by a factor of 8. I would be surprised if there is any faster way to scan for a byte in memory in **.NET**.

This returns the **index of the first occurrence of byte 'v'** within the range of memory starting at offset `i` (relative to address `src`), and continuing for length `c`. Returns **-1** if byte `v` is not found.

```
// fast IndexOf byte in memory. (To use this with managed byte[] array, see below)
public unsafe static int IndexOfByte(byte* src, byte v, int i, int c)
{
    ulong t;
    byte* p, pEnd;

    for (p = src + i; ((long)p & 7) != 0; c--, p++)
        if (c == 0)
            return -1;
        else if (*p == v)
            return (int)(p - src);

    ulong r = v; r |= r << 8; r |= r << 16; r |= r << 32;

    for (pEnd = p + (c & ~7); p < pEnd; p += 8)
    {
        t = *(ulong*)p ^ r;
        t = (t - 0x0101010101010101) & ~t & 0x8080808080808080;
        if (t != 0)
        {
            t &= (ulong)-(long)t;
            return (int)(p - src) + dbj8[t * 0x07EDD5E59A4E28C2 >> 58];
        }
    }

    for (pEnd += c & 7; p < pEnd; p++)
        if (*p == v)
            return (int)(p - src);

    return -1;
}
```

Don't be alarmed by the one multiplication you see; it's only executed a maximum of once per call of this function in order to do a final [deBruijn lookup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence). The read-only lookup table used for that is a simple shared list of 64 byte values which requires one-time only initialization:

```
// elsewhere in the static class...

readonly static sbyte[] dbj8 =
{
     7, -1, -1, -1, -1,  5, -1, -1, -1,  4, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
    -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,  6, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
    -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
    -1, -1, -1,  3, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,  1, -1,  2,  0, -1, -1,
};
```

The `-1` values are never accessed and can be left at zero if desired instead, as shown in the following alternative to the preceding table initialization code, if you prefer:

```
static MyStaticClass()
{
    dbj8 = new sbyte[64];  // initialize the lookup table (alternative to the above)
    dbj8[0x00] = 7;
    dbj8[0x18] = 6;
    dbj8[0x05] = 5;
    dbj8[0x09] = 4;
    dbj8[0x33] = 3;
    dbj8[0x3C] = 2;
    dbj8[0x3A] = 1;
 /* dbj8[0x3D] = 0; */
}

readonly static sbyte[] dbj8, dbj16;
```

For completeness, here is how to use the function with the method prototype provided by the OP in the original question.

```
/// Finds the first occurrence of a specific byte in a byte array.
/// If not found, returns -1.
public static unsafe int GetFirstOccurance(byte byteToFind, byte[] byteArray)
{
    fixed (byte* p = byteArray)
        return IndexOfByte(p, byteToFind, 0, byteArray.Length);
}
```

**Discussion**
My code is a bit intricate, so detailed examination is left as an exercise for the interested reader. You can study another take on the general approach of gang-wise memory searching in the **.NET** internal method [Buffer.IndexOfByte](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/buffer.cs,074d55cdee861694,references), but that code has significant drawbacks compared to mine:

- Most significantly, the .NET code only scans 4 bytes at time instead of 8 as in mine.
- It's a non-public method, so you'd need to use reflection to call it.
- The .NET code has a "performance leak" where the `t1 != 0` check gives a **false positive**, and the four checks that follow are wasted. Note their "fall-through" case: due to this false-positive, they need four final checks--thus allowing fall-through--to maintain correctness, instead of just three.
- The .NET code's false-positive is caused by an inherently inferior bitwise computation based on ***overflow*** of the carry bit from one byte to the next. This leads to [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) asymmetries (evidenced by their use of constants `0x7efefeff` or `0x81010100`) and the occasional "left-wise egress" (i.e., loss) of information regarding the most-significant byte, which is the real problem here. In contrast, I use an ***underflow*** computation which keeps each byte's computation independent of its neighbors'. My method gives a conclusive result in all cases with no false-positive or "fall-through" processing.
- My code uses a [branchless technique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence) for the final lookup. A handful of non-branching logical operations (plus one multiplication in this case) is generally believed to favor performance over extended `if-else` structures, since the latter can disrupt [CPU predictive caching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_predictor). This issue is more important for my 8-byte scanner because without using lookup I'd have twice as many `if-else` conditions in the final check, as compared to a 4-byte gang-wise scanner.

Of course if you're not concerned with all this minutiae you can just copy and use the code; I've unit-tested it quite exhaustively and verified correct behavior for all well-formed inputs. So while the core functionality is ready to use, you'll probably want to add argument checking.

---

[edit:]

```
String.IndexOf(String s, Char char, int ix_start, int count) ... fast!
```

Because the above method has worked so successfully in my projects, I extended it to cover 16-bit searching. Here is the same code adapted to search for a **16-bit short, ushort, or char** primitive instead of `byte`. This adapted method was also independently verified against its own respective unit-test methodology adapted from above.

```
static MyStaticClass()
{
    dbj16 = new sbyte[64];
 /* dbj16[0x3A] = 0; */
    dbj16[0x33] = 1;
    dbj16[0x05] = 2;
    dbj16[0x00] = 3;
}
readonly static sbyte[] dbj16;

public static int IndexOf(ushort* src, ushort v, int i, int c)
{
    ulong t;
    ushort* p, pEnd;

    for (p = src + i; ((long)p & 7) != 0; c--, p++)
        if (c == 0)
            return -1;
        else if (*p == v)
            return (int)(p - src);

    ulong r = ((ulong)v << 16) | v;
    r |= r << 32;

    for (pEnd = p + (c & ~7); p < pEnd; p += 4)
    {
        t = *(ulong*)p ^ r;
        t = (t - 0x0001000100010001) & ~t & 0x8000800080008000;
        if (t != 0)
        {
            i = dbj16[(t & (ulong)-(long)t) * 0x07EDD5E59A4E28C2 >> 58];
            return (int)(p - src) + i;
        }
    }

    for (pEnd += c & 7; p < pEnd; p++)
        if (*p == v)
            return (int)(p - src);

    return -1;
}
```

And below are the various overloads for accessing this for the remaining 16-bit primitives, plus `String` (last one shown):

```
public static int IndexOf(this char[] rg, char v) => IndexOf(rg, v, 0, rg.Length);
public static int IndexOf(this char[] rg, char v, int i, int c = -1)
{
    if (rg != null && (c = c < 0 ? rg.Length - i : c) > 0)
        fixed (char* p = rg)
            return IndexOf((ushort*)p, v, i, c < 0 ? rg.Length - i : c);
    return -1;
}

public static int IndexOf(this short[] rg, short v) => IndexOf(rg, v, 0, rg.Length);
public static int IndexOf(this short[] rg, short v, int i, int c = -1)
{
    if (rg != null && (c = c < 0 ? rg.Length - i : c) > 0)
        fixed (short* p = rg)
            return IndexOf((ushort*)p, (ushort)v, i, c < 0 ? rg.Length - i : c);
    return -1;
}

public static int IndexOf(this ushort[] rg, ushort v) => IndexOf(rg, v, 0, rg.Length);
public static int IndexOf(this ushort[] rg, ushort v, int i, int c = -1)
{
    if (rg != null && (c = c < 0 ? rg.Length - i : c) > 0)
        fixed (ushort* p = rg)
            return IndexOf(p, v, i, c < 0 ? rg.Length - i : c);
    return -1;
}
public static int IndexOf(String s, Char ch, int i = 0, int c = -1)
{
    if (s != null && (c = c < 0 ? s.Length - i : c) > 0)
        fixed (char* p = s)
            return IndexOf((ushort*)p, ch, i, c);
    return -1;
}
```

Notice that the `String` overload is not marked as an extension method since this higher-performance replacement version of the function would never be called that way (built-in methods with the same name always take precedence over extension methods). To use it as an extension on `String` instances, you can change the name of this method. As an example, `IndexOf__(this String s,...)` would cause it to appear *next to the built-in method name* in **Intellisense** listings, perhaps a helpful reminder to opt-in. Otherwise, if you don't need extension syntax, you can just make sure you call this optimized version directly as a static method of its own class when you want to use it instead of `s.IndexOf(Char ch)`.

Comment: WHoa, long answer. But at lease you might provide a result of benchmark compared to the rest, to prove your statement. And it will get more attention too.

Comment: Wow awesome, is there any documentation about the idea behind this?